# Is it possible to get the system color name from Data Color

Tags: swiftui

Is it possible to get the system color name when retrieving a color from Data?

Here is the code I'm using for encoding and decoding the colors.

```
extension Color {
    static func colorFrom(data:Data) -> Color {
        do {
            return try Color(NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: UIColor.self, from: data)!)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        return Color.clear
    }

    func encodeToData() -> Data {
        do {
            return try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: UIColor(self), requiringSecureCoding: false)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        return try! NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: UIColor.clear, requiringSecureCoding: false)
    }
}
```

##### Encoding a color

```
let color = Color.systemRed.encodeToData()
```

##### Decoding the same color. Here I would like to be able to get `systemRed` when I decode the color.

```
print("Color: \(Color.colorFrom(data: color).description)")
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: A Color object doesn’t have a name in that sense, there are static properties on Color that has names and holds a certain color. If you want to store a name you need to add that information yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it without modifications. `NSKeyedArchiver` does not encode `UIColor` and therefore `NSKeyedUnarchiver` can't decode `UIColor`. Here is how you can make your own version of `UIColor`. Note– even though I used `UIColor`, you can use `Color` if you want.

### 1. Create an object that holds a name and a color

There are a bunch of `UIColors`, so I only listed a few, but this is the basic concept:

```
struct ImprovedColor {
    var name: String?
    var color: UIColor
    
    static let systemColors: [String: UIColor] = [
        "systemRed": .systemRed,
        "systemBlue": .systemBlue,
        "systemGreen": .systemGreen,
        "black": .black
        //etc.
    ]
}
```

### 2. Create a new decoder

```
static func colorFrom(data: Data) -> ImprovedColor? {
        do {
            if let name = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: NSString.self, from: data) as? String {
                return ImprovedColor(name: name, color: systemColors[name] ?? .clear)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        return nil
    }
```

### 3. Create a new encoder

```
    func encodeToData() -> Data? {
        do {
            if let name = name {
                return try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: name, requiringSecureCoding: false)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        return nil
    }
```

### Everything together

```
struct ImprovedColor {
    var name: String?
    var color: UIColor
    
    static let systemColors: [String: UIColor] = [
        "systemRed": .systemRed,
        "systemBlue": .systemBlue,
        "systemGreen": .systemGreen,
        "black": .black
        //etc.
    ]
}

extension ImprovedColor {
    static func colorFrom(data: Data) -> ImprovedColor? {
        do {
            if let name = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: NSString.self, from: data) as? String {
                return ImprovedColor(name: name, color: systemColors[name] ?? .clear)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        return nil
    }

    func encodeToData() -> Data? {
        do {
            if let name = name {
                return try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: name, requiringSecureCoding: false)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

### Use the color

Now that you have the improved color, you can use it:

```
let niceRedColor = ImprovedColor(name: "systemRed", color: UIColor.systemRed)

if let data = niceRedColor.encodeToData(), let decodedColor = ImprovedColor.colorFrom(data: data) {
    print("Color: \(decodedColor.color.description), Name: \(decodedColor.name ?? "Color isn't known")")
}
```

Comment: Nice approach, thanks a lot.